# Create subclass object from another subclass object

Tags: java

There are three classes. One of them is parent class, and others are subclasses. For example:

Parent Class: `Parent`

Subclasses: `SubClass1, SubClass2`

My question is that how can I convert SubClass1 object into SubClass2 object without typecasting exception ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless you create an is-a relationship between them. Sibling type instances cannot be cast to eachother.

You will have to do something like:

```
SubClass2 extends Parent
SubClass1 extends Subclass2
```

Now both inherit from `Parent` and you can write

```
Subclass2 obj = new Subclass1();
```

Or do the reverse.

Comment: Yes I know. I think maybe, a super class object is created first subclass object than second subclass  object is created this super class

Comment: Yes I will do but I have to wait five minutes because of stackoverflow rules :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because `SubClass1` might have a member that `SubClass2` doesn't and the other way around.

Comment: Yes I know. I think maybe, a super class object is created first subclass object than second subclass object is created this super class

Answer (score 1):

Say that the parent is `Fruit` and the subclasses are `Banana` and `Apple`. You are asking how to make a `Banana` into an `Apple`? You can't. A banana isn't an apple. The exception is telling you exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You can fake the compiler but runtime you are assured to get ClassCastException

Answer (score 1):

You can't, and it would not really make sense to. Imagine you parent class being "Animal" and subclass1 an Elephant while subclass2 is a Mouse, what you are asking is for a way to look at the Elephant as if it was a Mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's possible!! **if you don't care about the lose of data in the new object**.

```
class Parent{
    String A;
    String B;
    public String getA();
    public String setA();
    public String getB();
    public String setB();
}
class SubClass1 extend Parent{
    String C;
    public String getC();
    public String setC();
}

class SubClass1 extend Parent{
    String D;
    public String getD();
    public String setD();
}

public SubClass1 convertTOSubClass2(SubClass2 obj2){
    SubClass1 obj1 = new SubClass1();
    obj1.setA(obj2.getA());
    obj1.setB(obj2.getB());
    ... 
    return obj1;
}
```

In this case, we simply ignore the **C** and **D**. I think it's OK for a few Fields (A,B) to set, but no good for many Fields(A-Z) or even Parent has Parent with many fields...

**I am also looking for better/elegant solution**, something like "*copy all fields of parent class object*", because sometimes we do want to **reuse** the data of the existing object.

**== UPDATE ==**

**Apache BeanUtils**: copyProperties(Object,Object) could be helpful.